# computing the average of variables with missing values in Stata

Tags: average, stata

I know how to calculate the avarage of variables without missing value, but I am not sure about calculating it with missing values. For example we have 6 area halls as follows:

```
area_hall_1 area_hall_2 area_hall_3 area_hall_4 area_hall_5 area_hall_6
580         580         650         .           .           .
1000        1000        .           .           .           
825         825         .           .           .           .
912         912         .           .           .           .
670         .           .           .           .           .
790         .           .           .           .           .
750         900         1000        1000        900     750
```

Comment: you're new here, please improve your question, what do the numbers mean ? which numbers are for which area ? and what average you to calculate the downvote was from me

Comment: Your question is about missing values and you show none in your example data. Why? Please show us what you think you know; what have you attempted? If the mean is across variables (i.e. mean of area1, area2, etc.) see `help egen`, with the `rowmean()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have already used the rowmean() function to calculate the average of each row but it includes the missing values and I want to be like this, for example:                averae =(580+580+650)/3   it takes too much time to do this process. So I want to do it in easy way for all observations

Answer (score 1):

The reported (or rather implied) problem makes no sense whatsoever. Consider the data posted (an extra missing value is needed in the second observation).

```
. clear 
. input area_hall_1 area_hall_2 area_hall_3 area_hall_4 area_hall_5 area_hall_6

     area_ha~1  area_ha~2  area_ha~3  area_ha~4  area_ha~5  area_ha~6
 1. 580         580         650         .           .           .
 2. 1000        1000        .           .           .           . 
 3. 825         825         .           .           .           .
 4. 912         912         .           .           .           .
 5. 670         .           .           .           .           .
 6. 790         .           .           .           .           .
 7. 750         900         1000        1000        900     750
 8. end 

. egen area_hall_mean = rowmean(area_hall_?) 

. egen area_hall_count = rownonmiss(area_hall_?) 

. l *_mean *_count , sep(0) 

     +---------------------+
     | area_h~n   area_h~t |
     |---------------------|
  1. | 603.3333          3 |
  2. |     1000          2 |
  3. |      825          2 |
  4. |      912          2 |
  5. |      670          1 |
  6. |      790          1 |
  7. | 883.3333          6 |
     +---------------------+

 . di (580+580+650)/3
 603.33333
```

The `egen` function `rowmean()` ignores missing values. How it could do otherwise? The only other possibility is to report that a mean cannot be calculated because there are missing values. That is defensible, but not at all typical Stata style. So the means reported are exactly those the OP wants. An independent calculation with `display` shows that the means reported are those desired. (A profound sceptic is at liberty to inspect the code with `viewsource _growmean.ado`.)

Comment: Thank you Nick for your help.I repeated the same steps, but that dose not exclude missing values. I mean each row is divided by 6. it dose not give me this result as you got it.

Comment: I see no reproducible example in your comment or your question. Try to repeat the code above in may answer.

Comment: Here is my output. it accounts for the missing values in calculation.                                                                                         . egen area_hall_mean = rowmean(area_hall_?) 
. egen area_hall_count = rownonmiss(area_hall_?) 
. l *_mean *_count , sep(0) 
     +---------------------+
     | area_h~n   area_h~t |
     |---------------------|
  1. | 193.3333          6 |
  2. | 333.3333          6 |
  3. |      275          6 |
  4. |      304          6 |
  5. | 111.6667          6 |
  6. | 131.6667          6 |
  7. |      125          6 |

Comment: Please edit your question. The comment above is too difficult to read.